# how to do this in bash script

Tags: linux, bash

in Linux, suppose mount command return this

```
/dev/sdc1 on /media/ELF (^-^)V type vfat 
/dev/sdb1 on /media/PENDRIVE type vfat
```

all I want to do is get all mount point of my usb disk.

I did that already, using combination of grep and sed I can get these:

```
/media/ELF (^-^)V
/media/PENDRIVE
```

the problem is, when I do for loop in bash, those text will become 3 part instead of 2 parts , I mean :

suppose I put the result of those text in LIST

```
for list in $LIST; do
    echo $list
done;
```

the result of that for loop becomes

```
/media/ELF
(^-^)V
/media/PENDRIVE
```

how to handle this issue? or are there any easier ways to get mount point of my usb disk?

Thanks

Comment: You could pipe the lines into `awk '{print $1}'` to remove all but the first whitespace-separated word.

Comment: How did you put them into the LIST variable? An option is to use a bash array, then you can do `for list in "${LIST[@]}";...`.

Comment: this is how I do it LIST=`mount | grep /media | grep uhelper=udisks | sed -e 's/\/dev\/.*on //g' -e 's/ type .*//g'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've already extracted the mountpoint paths and the only issue is to process them in a loop:

```
while read -r mountpoint; do
  echo "[$mountpoint]"
done < <(mount | grep /media | grep uhelper=udisks | sed -e 's/\/dev\/.*on //g' -e 's/ type .*//g')
```

Comment: thanks for reply, sorry but in my case there is no \n between the text, I think they only separated by space

Comment: @BobAlmond Based on your command above (`mount | ...`) you should definitely get *multiple lines* back, so the problem may be in how you capture the output. I've updated my answer to directly incorporate your command - see if that works.